# How to deal with async initialized data in Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, async-await, constructor, components

The data needed to load my component is being retrieved by first reading `ActivatedRoute.queryParams`, second making some API call. As both an async constructor and an async call inside `ngOnInit` won't work to somehow defer component initialization, inside my component I must assume my data being undefined, which leads to a number of tedious `if` cases.

One way around this is not to use `this.data` but let my class methods take the data as an argument. With one single check `*ngIf="data != null"` at the template root, passing the non-undefined data around requires no nullish checks anymore.

But this is not really how class fields should be used I guess. **So what's the recommended way to deal with asynchronously initialized component data?**

I was for example thinking of some `ready` flag plus telling typescript that if `ready` is truthy, `data` is not undefined. But I don't really know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article could help you.

This article is about angular 13, but should work in older/ Newer versions as well.

"In angular 13, how can I get all API data before rendering the Page?"

https://royeraadames.medium.com/in-angular-13-how-can-i-get-all-api-data-before-rendering-the-page-93ee045b9c09

Let me know if this was helpfull or you need some more help!

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice approach. But I still need to subscribe for the data, so it does not really solve the problem, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Together with @alexdefender93 answer this is working now, using `this.route.snapshot.data`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 asynchronous streams - the api call and queryParams. You need to combine them both and get the result when both emitted. It can be easily achieved with RxJS:

```
combineLatest([this.activatedRoute.queryParams, this.api.getData$()])
  .pipe(take(1)) // take(1) completes the observable after 1 emit
  .subscribe(([params, data]) => {
    // TODO implement initialisation logic
  });
```

On this example we assume that `this.api.getData$()` is your API call that returns Observable. If you need to display this data in your template or pass it to some child component ( using `async` pipe ) you can make an Observable instead of using `subscribe`. For example:

```
this.data$ = combineLatest([this.activatedRoute.queryParams, this.api.getData$()]).pipe(
  map(([params, data]) => {
    // TODO process the data
  })
);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's really not answering my question...

Comment: Apparently I didn't understand the problem you're trying to solve. If you want to use a route resolver mentioned in Kerschbaumer Stefan's answer but get the data synchronously you can access it using this.route.snapshot.data where route = ActivatedRouteSnapshot.

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I was looking for!